# Pickup existing messages using Azure Function App binding with Service Bus

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, function-binding

We have an Azure Function app binding setup with Service bus, so that it is triggered when a message goes onto a Queue. However imagine if we disable the Function app, or it is down for whatever reason and some messages backlog onto the Service bus Queue.

How do we then re-trigger the Function app for existing messages? It only appears to pickup new messages. I can't see it just picking existing ones off. Is there a way to make it retrigger itself for existing messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to re trigger the function, if your received becomes unavailable the messages will stay in the queue until a working receiver picks them up.

What makes you think its not behaving like this?

Could it be that you have multiple receivers?

Comment: This has been a learning piece, you are correct. It just takes a short while for it to pick them up again but it DOES eventually pick them up.